# I am uploading multiple files and id from angular to node server , but i am getting of error of bad request from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, multer

//I am trying to upload multiples files from angular with id and sending it in the form of FormData to node server, but the server is throwing the error of bad request.

//I have tried to tweak my body-parser but it didn't work

//This is my from for the image upload.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
   <form [formGroup]="uploadImage" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitImage()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input formControlName="image" name="image" type="file" (change)="onImagePicked($event)" multiple/><br/>
         <br>
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

//This is the code for my component

```
onImagePicked(e: any) {
 console.log('functions')
this.fileList = e.target.files;
console.log(this.fileList);
this.uploadImage.value.image = this.fileList;
this.uploadImage.value.id = this.id;
console.log(this.uploadImage.value)
this.masterservice.onUploads(this.uploadImage.value)
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
}
```

//This is the code for the service sending the request to node server

```
onUploads(id) {
       console.log(id);
       const postData = new FormData();
       postData.append('id', id.id)
       const files: Array<File> = id.image;
       console.log(files)
       for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
           console.log(files)
           postData.append('image[]', files[i], files[i]["name"]);
       }
       console.log(postData.get("image[]"), postData.get('id'))
       // for(var val of postData.values()){
       //     console.log(val)
       // }
       return this.http.post<any>('http://192.168.43.124:3000/api/addProjectImages', postData)
           .map(res => {
               return res;
           });
   }
```

//this the code for my backend.

```
router.post("/api/addProjectImages", upload.array("image[]", 10), (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.body, req.files);
 // console.log(req.files[1], req.body.image[1]);
 let data = [];
 if (!req.files) {
   const msg = "Please upload a valid file.";
   sendData(req, res, msg, 0);
 }
 const url = req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host");
 let image = [];
 for (i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
   image.push(url + "/uploads/" + req.files[i].filename);
 }
 project.findOne({ _id: req.body.id }).then(project => {
   console.log(image);
   for (const img of image) {
     project.images.push(img);
   }
   project
     .save()
     .then(editedProject => {
       sendData(req, res, editedProject, 1);
     })
     .catch(err => {
       sendData(req, res, err, 0);
     });
 });
});
```

I want to get the files uploaded but the backend is throwing an error of bad request.

Comment: `the backend is throwing an error`, what error? It would probably help to know what Node is telling you :) It's probably not saying only `bad request`.

Comment: Bad request.....unexpected token o at JSON position 0

Comment: ah... Also, you have a `upload.array` middleware, what is that?

Comment: @JeremyThille It's for uploading multiple files through multer